# Make NA values for the specific condition in R using for sentence

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I made a data `df` like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3),
                 year=c(2011,2012,2013,2010,2011,2012,2013,2012,2013),
                 weight=c(42,44,47,60,NA,65,66,NA,70),
                 temperature=c(NA,36,37,36,37,NA,36,36,NA))
```

My goal is to give two conditions to `weight` and make the values NA's satisfying the conditions.
`cond1` is the condition that `weight` is less than 44. The other condition `cond2` is the condition that `weight` is bigger than 66. So if I run the code below, `weight` should be `weight=c(NA,44,47,60,NA,65,66,NA,NA)`. However, the result is not I wanted.

I tried the code below:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3),
                 year=c(2011,2012,2013,2010,2011,2012,2013,2012,2013),
                 weight=c(42,44,47,60,NA,65,66,NA,70),
                 temperature=c(NA,36,37,36,37,NA,36,36,NA))
cond1<-df$weight< 44
cond2<-df$weight> 66
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(cond1){df$weight[i]=NA}
  else if(cond2){df$weight[i]=NA}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without loops using `ifelse` and `|` (or):

```
df$weight <- ifelse(df$weight < 44 | df$weight > 66, NA, df$weight)

df$weight
[1] NA 44 47 60 NA 65 66 NA NA
```